# How to create json file

Tags: c#, json

I have write a C# Program to Generate "Json" File for Eway Bill Uploading

My Json Format is :- (Its not working When I upload in EwayBill)

Please help me,how to do this

```
[{"Supply Type":"Outward","Sub Type":"Export","Doc Type":"Tax Invoice","Doc No":"PK/18/0015","Doc Date":"16/02/2018 00:00:00","From_OtherPartyName":"KH Exports  India Private Limited Glove Division","From_GSTIN":"33AAACR1714R1ZA","From_Address1":"142/1,Trunk Road","From_Address2":"Perumugai","From_Place":"Vellore","From_Pin Code":"632009","From_State":"Tamil Nadu","To_OtherPartyName":"K H EXPORTS INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED","To_GSTIN":"33AAACR1714R1ZA","To_Address1":"GLOVE DIVISION, GODOWN","To_Address2":"NEW NO. 24, KUMARAPPA STREET,","To_Place":"Chennai","To_Pin Code":"600003","To_State":"Tamil Nadu","Product":"FINISHED LEATHER GLOVES FOR LADIES","Description":"","HSN":"42032920","Unit":"PAIRS","Qty":"25","Assessable Value":"678","Tax Rate (S+C+I+Cess)":"9+9+0+0","CGST Amount":"6102","SGST Amount":"6102","IGST Amount":"0","CESS Amount":"0","Trans Mode":"Road","Distance (Km)":"115","Trans Name":"","Trans ID":"","Trans DocNo":"","Trans Date":"","Vehicle No":"TN23CB8274","Errors List":""}]
```

The below json is working fine (I get this json from eway bill website)

```
{
"version":"1.0.0123",
    "billLists":[{
           "userGstin":"29BQSPA3829E124",
           "supplyType":"O",
           "subSupplyType":1,
           "docType":"INV",
           "docNo":"1234",
           "docDate":"04/03/2017",
           "fromGstin":"29BQSPA3829E124",
           "fromTrdName":"HUKKERI PVT LTD",
           "fromAddr1":"OLD AIRPORT ROAD",
           "fromAddr2":"OLD AIRPORT ROAD",
           "fromPlace":"BANGALORE",
           "fromPincode":560090,
           "fromStateCode":29,
           "toGstin":"29AAACG0569P1Z3",
           "toTrdName":"AMBUJA PVT LTD",
           "toAddr1":"MG ROAD",
           "toAddr2":"MG ROAD",
           "toPlace":"BANGALORE",
           "toPincode":560090,
           "toStateCode":29,
           "totalValue":678,
           "cgstValue":6102,
           "sgstValue":6102,
           "igstValue":0,
           "cessValue":0,
           "transMode":1,
           "transDistance":567,
           "transporterName":"",
           "transporterId":"",
           "transDocNo":"",
           "transDocDate":"",
           "vehicleNo":"KA12KA1234",
                     "itemList":[{
                            "itemNo":1,
                            "productName":"STEEL",
                            "productDesc":"STEEL",
                            "hsnCode":26180000,
                            "quantity":0,
                            "qtyUnit":"KGS",
                            "taxableAmount":678,
                            "sgstRate":9,
                            "cgstRate":9,
                            "igstRate":0,
                            "cessRate":0
                          }

                          ]
           }

      ]
}
```

I have tried below but its not solved...please check this code...

```
public bool WriteJason(DataTable dt, string path)
    {
        try
        {

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List&lt;Dictionary&lt;string, string>> rows = new List&lt;Dictionary&lt;string, string>>();
            Dictionary&lt;string, string> row = null;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary&lt;string, string>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim().ToString(), Convert.ToString(dr[col]));
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            string jsonstring = serializer.Serialize(rows);

            using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, false))
            {
                file.Write(jsonstring);
                file.Close();
                file.Dispose();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: use newtonsoft json framework it is more user friendly and easier.

Answer (score 3):

As @mcy mentionned in a comment, you'll have an easier time using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

To expand a little on this idea, I would personally take this approach:

1. Define a model that matches your Json-structure:

   ```
   private class JsonModel
   {
       public string Version { get; set; }
       public IList<JsonBillModel> BillLists { get; set; } = new List<JsonBillModel>();
   }

   private class JsonBillModel
   {
       public string UserGstin { get; set; }
       public string SupplyType { get; set; }
       public int SubSupplyType { get; set; }
       public string DocType { get; set; }
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Create an instance of your model

   ```
   var model = new JsonModel
   {
       Version = "1.0.0123",
       BillLists =
       {
           new JsonBillModel
           {
               UserGstin = "29BQSPA3829E124",
               SupplyType = "O",
               SubSupplyType = 1,
               DocType = "INV"
               //...
           }
       }
   };
   ```
3. Serialze your model to Json using Json.NET:

   ```
   var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
   serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, serializerSettings);
   File.WriteAllText(path, json);
   ```

*The reason we create an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` with a `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` contract resolver is that our model would otherwise generate [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) keys in our Json (since our model is written in a PascalCase-format. If this sounds confusing, try leaving out the ContractResolver-line and see the result for yourself.*

4. Write a test to ensure that your Json output matches your desired output, using your favourite testing library.

---

Sidenote: you can also use Json.NET to convert json into an instance of your model.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option to create a JSON file.

1. using text editor like notepad
2. using online tools like [JSON parser](https://jsonparser.org/)
3. Create a file from the JSON URL

if you want full process it provide in [Learning Container](https://www.learningcontainer.com/how-to-create-json-file/).